# Unwanted new lines using python Popen and pandoc to parse html?

Tags: python, latex, html-parsing, popen, pandoc

I am trying to convert several pieces of html to latex using python and pandoc and I have got stuck with a couple of problems.

To communicate my python script with pandoc I use `subprocess.Popen`, redirecting `stdout` to a file I am saving for including it in a latex template.

If I use the classic way of implementing `Popen`

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

filedesc = open('myfile.tex','w')
args = ['pandoc', '-f', 'html', '-t', 'latex']
p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
outp, err = p.communicate(input=html)
filedesc.write(outp)
```

I get the lines with an additional new line where there shouldn't be any:

> > \textbf{M. John Harrison} (Rugby, Warckwickshire, 1945) is a contemporary
>
> >
>
> > English writer.

This is (misteriously?) easy to solve by changing the `stdout=PIPE` to the file descriptor:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

filedesc = open('myfile.tex','w')
args = ['pandoc', '-f', 'html', '-t', 'latex']
p = Popen(args, stdout=filedesc, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
outp, err = p.communicate(input=html)
# not needed
# filedesc.write(outp)
```

But if I want to use a string buffer, the same problem occurs, since i cannot use it as the stdout parameter.

Any idea on how to stop Popen/pandoc from doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a "kind of bug" in python's PIPE (???).

**I am executing this code in a Windows system.** This means that when a new line is entered, they are in the CR+LF (\r\n) style rather than the (cleaner) LF (\n) new line in unix-style.

At the time I introduce a large html text to be converted by pandoc, the output is returned by the pipe to the command line. Thus, every time the standard column width is reached, an ugly "new line" character is introduced. In my case, a CR+LF. This was making my output look so weird.

The dirty solution I have implemented is to add a `replace('\r\n','\n')` before writing the output but I am not sure if it's the most elegant one.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

html = '<p><b>Some random html code</b> longer than 80 columns ... </p>'
filedesc = open('myfile.tex','w')
args = ['pandoc', '-f', 'html', '-t', 'latex']
p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
outp, err = p.communicate(input=html)
filedesc.write(outp.replace('\r\n','\n'))**strong text**
```